# django-tagging Error in formatting: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_base_manager'

Tags: python, django, django-tagging

Struggling to understand an error with a Django application [django-tagging](https://django-tagging.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#) (v 0.4.6) using Django 1.11.9 and Django Grapelli 2.10.1

It has a [basic installation](https://django-tagging.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#installation) and I can use it just find to tag the models within my application.

The default install includes two admin objects - Tagged Items and Tags.

[image]

Tags works just fine however Tagged Items returns this error:

```
AttributeError at /admin/tagging/taggeditem/

'NoneType' object has no attribute '_base_manager'
```

Here's a screen shot:

[image]

Just wondering if anyone is familiar with this particular set up and can suggest how to address this problem?